# C Memory Error Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, memory, free

I am getting the following error when running my program.

Debug Assertion Failed!
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c
Line: 1322
Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

So I debugged my program and found out that the problem occurred when the following function was called the second time, more specifically the free statement at the end.

```
int writeToLog(char* str, enum LOGLEVEL logLevel) {
    if(logFile && logLevel >= level) {
        FILE* log;
        char *now = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
        time_t timer = time(NULL);
        if(*now == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }       
        now = ctime(&timer);
        if(now[strlen(now) - 1] == '\n') {
            now[strlen(now) - 1] = '\0';
        }
        log = fopen(logFile, "a+");
        if (log == NULL)
            return -1;
        fprintf(log, "%s%s\n", now, str);
        fclose(log);
        free(now); //fails here on the second function call
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I would love to just make `now` a constant char array but visual studio isn't letting me do that because of the return type of ctime. Can anyone help?
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the pointer `now` with a different one returned by `ctime`. Then you are trying to free it. So you end up freeing the pointer returned by `ctime`, and not the pointer you allocated yourself.

You are not supposed to modify the pointer returned by `ctime`.

For your purposes, you don't even need to allocate any memory at all. You can just use the pointer returned by `ctime` directly.

So this should work just fine:

```
int writeToLog(char* str, enum LOGLEVEL logLevel) {
    if(logFile && logLevel >= level) {
        FILE* log;
        time_t timer = time(NULL);

        const char *now = ctime(&timer);

        size_t length = strlen(now);
        if(now[length - 1] == '\n') {
            now[length - 1] = '\0';
        }
        log = fopen(logFile, "a+");
        if (log == NULL)
            return -1;
        fprintf(log, "%s%s\n", now, str);
        fclose(log);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that you make two calls to `strlen(now)`. You should call it once and save the result.

Comment: Thanks. By the way I think now needs to be just a normal char instead of constant, as it has the potential of being changed due to the new line stripping just below it.